# Can a Binary Tree be recovered after performing Morris Postorder Traversal?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, postorder

Morris Postorder Traversal alters the Binary Tree. Is it possible to recover the initial tree after the traversal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would change the tree back after the traversal.

Look at the detailed answer here: [Can we use Morris traversal for postorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384599/can-we-use-morris-traversal-for-postorder)

It has a great code example. Just might save you some headache.